# Access Database Default Date cannot contain 00 hour, 00 min or 00 sec

Tags: ms-access, vb6

So, we have an old VB 6 App written many many years ago.
It uses an Access Database to store data, and the VB6 App as the interface to this data
Now, to change the VB6 app would be quite difficult, and I'm trying to avoid this.
The problem is, when the VB6 inserts data into a table in the access database, the table has a column which uses 'Now()' to set the default value.
Now there are calculations done on this date and time value, including multiplication. So.. when any of the date/time components are 0, the final result is 0.
I.E **dd * mm * yy * hh * n * s** - If any are zero, the result is zero
To overcome this I can

• Change the code to specify the date (not very ideal)

• *hopefully* in the default value of the Access Database put some validation to make sure there are no 0 values in the time
Is there any way to validate the default value like this?
Something like

```
If DatePart(‘hh’,date) == 0 OR DatePart(‘n’,date) = 0 OR DatePart(‘s’,Date) = 0
Then add one to all of them.
```

*Edit*
This is not my code, this is code written way before I, and ther other developers started. 
We can't be certain the code we have is the code being used in production. Hence why I'd rather not change code. We are planning on re-writing this soon, when time permits. 
The problem only occurs once or twice a month, so it's not vital to the running of the application.

Comment: Who in the world wrote that and didn't test it? Woof.

Comment: Yeah my thoughts exactly, we are slowly replacing this type of code. We could have our own DailyWTF internally due to the amount of stupid code.

Comment: Yah, I'd bite bullet and change that piece. Why the heck are they multiplying the date parts together? To get some kind of unique identifier?

Comment: Yes I don't know why it using this method to get a unqiue number, plenty of better ways to do it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it may not be ideal to edit the VB6 application, it would be the most robust way of dealing with the problem.

Your proposal to alter the data itself seems like a very bad idea since it can potentially throw off dates if the data were ever to be used by another application later on.  Better to let the application, with its unique requirements, transform the data at runtime to perform the calculations.

Always store your data in the most standard, normalized format possible.  You have no idea who will be using that data years from now when you're no longer working there.  The last thing you want is the bad karma of a new developer cursing your name because you thought it would be a good idea to alter the standard format for storing dates in a database.

It is also worth noting that many Date() objects or date libraries already have ways of calculating the number of seconds in a particular date, so it could even simplify your code.

Comment: The reason I want to avoid changing the VB6 code is becuase I'm not sure we have the production code, as the guy who wrote it liked to leave mulitple copies over a nice amount of network shares, and we will be replacing this application soon with a nice, new and non-dailyWTF material application :)

Comment: So set up some version control software like SVN and start using that instead of a network share, that's just silly.  Next, use a diff tool to compare the various scattered versions.  Lastly, get your hands dirty and find the right copy and edit that; being lazy and trying to modify the data rather than the application is dangerously foolish in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done using the column's `DEFAULT`.

You could create a 'helper' procedure to generate the date e.g. (Access Database Engine [ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access/HP030704831033.aspx) syntax):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddOrderWithDefaultDate
(
  arg_OrderID INTEGER, 
  arg_CustomerID NVARCHAR(5), 
  arg_EmployeeID INTEGER 
)
AS 
INSERT INTO Orders (OrderID, CustomerID, EmployeeID, OrderDate) 
SELECT DISTINCT arg_OrderID, arg_CustomerID, arg_EmployeeID, 
       DATE() 
          + TIMESERIAL(
                       IIF(DATEPART('H', NOW()) = 0, 1, DATEPART('H', NOW())), 
                       IIF(DATEPART('N', NOW()) = 0, 1, DATEPART('N', NOW())), 
                       IIF(DATEPART('N', NOW()) = 0, 1, DATEPART('S', NOW()))
                      ) AS OrderDate
       FROM Products;
```

Prior to the ACE (2007) version of the Access Database Engine you could remove the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` privileges from the table and grant to your 'helper' procedures.

Additionally, you should add a `CHECK` constraint or Validation Rule to the column to ensure the ensure the column is not explicitly inserted or updated using an illegal value. Yes, you need this even when privileges are only on your 'helper' functions, unless you are the mythical kind of coder who only writes bug-free code ;)

But, frankly, why bother? It sounds like there is a problem with your business logic being unable to handle zeros in `DATETIME` values. Don't just to treat the symptoms: cure the disease and fix the faulty logic,

Answer (score 0):

how about changing the function that multiplies all the date parts so that it adds one to all the date parts and then multiplies them?  no need tocheck for zero first, really, at least in theory.